# Mulesoft - SFTP Component to go through SOCKS Proxy

Tags: proxy, jvm, mule, sftp, socks

I was hoping someone could help.

I am trying to sftp to a remote server that is behind a firewall. I have a proxy setup and can sftp via the unix terminal succesfully. However when using mulesofts SFTP connector I get a timeout. From research it looks like this is because it is run on the JVM.

Mule comes with wrapper.conf to update any jvm settings so I have set the following settings:

**wrapper.java.additional.15**=-DsocksProxyHost:*hostname*

**wrapper.java.additional.16**=-DsocksProxyPort=1080

When I do this the Mule service no longer runs and get the following error:

WrapperManager Error: Unexpected exception opening backend socket: java.net.SocketException: Can't connect to SOCKS proxy:Invalid argument or cannot assign requested address

Hopefully someone can assist.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps typo in the

```
-DsocksProxyHost:hostname
```

Should be = rather than :.

The port is unnecessary, 1080 is the default. Documentation is here, see section 2.4 for SOCKS

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/net/proxies.html

Comment: Thank you for your response. I had a typo on my question the **wrapper.conf does contain: wrapper.java.additional.15=-DsocksProxyHost=hostname** I have also checked to ensure the port etc is not in use but unfortuantely still get the error

Comment: Try seeing what wrapper is actually giving to the jvm. There should be some log or debug mode where it will tell you the command it is executing. If on a linux system, move the socks parameter up to the front of the parameter list and use ps -ef to see it in the process list.